# file not shown in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, package-management, dependencies

well , i am stuck here.
when i connect android device on my ubuntu trusty 14.04 , the sd card not shown , then i accidentally uninstall udisks2 , then all file in my desktop and file explorer has been gone. But i can access file through terminal.

Then i try to install `udisks2` again,

```
pralad@pralad:~$ sudo apt-get install udisks2
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
udisks2 is already the newest version.
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer 
 required:
    libgconf2-4
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove it.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 26 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
 After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used. 
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
   Setting up heroku (3.99.4) ...
+ uname -m
 + MACHINE_TYPE=i686
 + [ i686 = x86_64 ]
  + ARCH=x32
  + mkdir -p /usr/local
  + cd /usr/local
   + + tar xz
      wget -qO- https://cli-assets.heroku.com/heroku-
  cli/channels/stable/heroku-cli-linux-x32.tar.gz

   gzip: stdin: unexpected end of file
   tar: Child returned status 1
     tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
      No apport report written because the error message indicates its 
 a followup error from a previous failure.
                      dpkg: error processing package heroku (--configure):
      subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
       dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of heroku-
       toolbelt:
         heroku-toolbelt depends on heroku (= 3.99.4); however:
        Package heroku is not configured yet. 
      dpkg: error processing package heroku-toolbelt (--configure):
         dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
           Errors were encountered while processing:
       heroku
        heroku-toolbelt
             E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: That seems to be an unrelated error due to (non-)availability of the `https://cli-assets.heroku.com/heroku-
  cli/channels/stable/heroku-cli-linux-x32.tar.gz` file.

Comment: @steeldriver, i removed heroku. i don't  have file explorer neither any file in my desktop.